# How to align textview in wrap content right for bigger screen in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

[My Layout]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Login"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/efield"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView_username" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Username :"
        android:id="@+id/textView_username"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView_attempt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Password :"
        android:id="@+id/textView_password"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView_attempt_count"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/editText_pass"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/editText_pass"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_user"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_username"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_password"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView_password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_user" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Attempts :"
        android:id="@+id/textView_attempt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_username"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView_username" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView_attempt_count"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_attempt"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_password"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:background="@drawable/statelistdrawable"
        android:textColor="@drawable/txco"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView_time"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/textView_time"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_FP"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:id="@+id/button_FP"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

My Layout [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJYwI.jpg)

Want to remove space between "Username" textview and "Name" edittext in Landscape. My layout is looking proper in portrait but gives space in between textview and edittext in landscape.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the content of your layout file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code, preferably in the form of a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).